# Individual-based simulation in r

Tags: r, simulation

My coding issue is best explained by first describing the system and data I'm working with. Then I'll present my problem/ask my question.

I am trying simulate the growth and development of individual insects within a population. Development is driven largely by temperature. As such, development is measured in "accumulated heat", i.e., more heat equals more development. There is, however, a temperature below which no development can occur (the "base").

Each insect passes through multiple stages during development and each stage has a unique base temperature.

Finally, the amount of heat required to advance from one stage to the next varies among individuals.

Okay, some example data:

```
# df1: Hourly temperatures
df1 = data.frame(DateTime = seq(
  from = as.POSIXct("1986-1-1 0:00"),
  to = as.POSIXct("1986-1-8 23:00"), 
  by = "hour"))

temp = c(5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,13,17,22,25,26,28,26,25,25,22,19,14,10,8,5,5)

df1$temp <- temp 

# df2: Each row is an individual insect. 
#      s1_thresh is the number of degrees that need to accumulate for each 
#      individual to advance from stage 1 to stage 2. 

df2 <- data.frame(id = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
              s1_thresh = c(21.5, 25.1, 19.9, 20.4, 21.4))

# Stage-specific base temperatures below which no degrees accumulate

base_s1 <- 10.5  # base temp for stage 1
base_s2 <- 8.6   # base temp for stage 2

# Temperature accumulation above base_s1 
df1$dd_s1 <- ifelse(temp >= base_s1, (temp - base_s1)/24, 0)
df1$cumdd_s1 <- cumsum(df1$dd_s1)
```

**Here is my question:** Since each individual will transition/advance stages at independent times due to the non-uniformity in heat requirements, how can I shift the base temperature for each individual when this transition occurs? Here is a desired outcome (sort of) for individual "A" from df1.

```
# Example for single individual:
# Individual "A" has s1_thresh of 21.5, so a shift to base_2 occurs on 1986-01-04 16:00:00, row 89
df1$dd_s2 <-  ifelse(df1$cumdd_s1 > df2$s1_thresh[df2$id == "A"] & temp >= base_s2, (temp - base_s2)/24, 0) 
df1$cumdd_s2 <- cumsum(df1$dd_s2)
```

I'm trying to avoid having multiple temperature accumulation columns for each individual, yet it is important to know the amount of heat that accumulates for each individual during a limited time frame.

Many many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want a vector of accumulated stage 2 degree days for each individual:

```
# transformed temperatures series relative to stages
df1$temps_b1 <- pmax(df1$temp - base_s1, 0)
df1$temps_b2 <- pmax(df1$temp - base_s2, 0)

ddsum <- function(theid) {
  in_stage1 <- cumsum(df1$temps_b1/24) < df2$s1_thresh[df2$id==theid]
  s2_temp <- ifelse(in_stage1, 0, df1$temps_b2)
  return(cumsum(s2_temp/24))
}

res<-as.data.frame(sapply(df2$id, FUN=ddsum))
names(res) <- df2$id
res
```

Comment: Thank you @dschwilk! This works beautifully and is exactly what I asked for. One last question for you: Can you explain a tiny bit about how [df2$id==theid] and function(theid) are related? What is happening there?

Comment: I went ahead and used your global objects (df1, df2) in my example.  So, df2$s1_thresh[df2$id==theid] is just using df2 as a dictionary or map object.  I filtered the s1_thresh column based on the id column.  The code assumes that ids are unique (if not, you'll just get the threshold of the first one). the function definition just allows us to combine the two steps (determine what stage the individual is in and then calculate stage 2 degree days in a single function we can pass to sapply()